# How can I prevent switch checkbox elements from overlapping another?

Tags: html, css, animation, checkbox, switch-statement

A want to put tree switch on my page. The switch are based on checkbox, and when I try to add more they stay one over the other. this is my code on fiddle: `https://jsfiddle.net/kdh8zyo0/`

All I want to do is add more two switch one above (not over) other. Like:

> Switch 1
>
> Switch 2
>
> Switch 3

The full code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head> 
<style>
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #179b77;
}

.colorful-switch {
  display: block; 
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 280px;
  height: 120px;
  margin-left: -140px;
  margin-top: -60px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #000000;
}
.colorful-switch:before {
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  top: -5px;
  width: 290px;
  height: 130px;
  border-radius: 55px;
  /*    COR DA BORDA */
  background: #000000;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
}
.colorful-switch:hover:before {
/*    COR DA BORDA hover */
  background: #13232f;
}
.colorful-switch__checkbox {
 z-index: -10;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 opacity: 0;
}
.colorful-switch__label {
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.colorful-switch__bg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 840px;
  height: 100%;
  
 /* background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, #ffffff 0, #ffffff 280px, #ffffff 560px, #ffffff  100%);*/
  
  background: linear-gradient(120deg, #179b77 0, #33FF99 280px, #FF3300 560px, #ff0000   100%);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-560px, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(-560px, 0, 0);
}
.colorful-switch__checkbox:checked ~ .colorful-switch__label .colorful-switch__bg {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.colorful-switch__dot {
  position: absolute;
  left: 204px;
  top: 50%;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  margin-left: -4px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.colorful-switch__checkbox:checked ~ .colorful-switch__label .colorful-switch__dot {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-125px, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(-125px, 0, 0);
}
.colorful-switch__on {
  position: absolute;
  left: 177px;
  top: 35px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 56px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.colorful-switch__checkbox:checked ~ .colorful-switch__label .colorful-switch__on {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-125px, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(-125px, 0, 0);
}
.colorful-switch__on__inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s 0s cubic-bezier(0.52, -0.96, 0.51, 1.28);
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s 0s cubic-bezier(0.52, -0.96, 0.51, 1.28);
  transition: transform 0.25s 0s cubic-bezier(0.52, -0.96, 0.51, 1.28);
  transition: transform 0.25s 0s cubic-bezier(0.52, -0.96, 0.51, 1.28), -webkit-transform 0.25s 0s cubic-bezier(0.52, -0.96, 0.51, 1.28);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
          transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0) translateZ(0);
          transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0) translateZ(0);
}
.colorful-switch__checkbox:checked ~ .colorful-switch__label .colorful-switch__on__inner {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.67, -0.16, 0.47, 1.61);
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.67, -0.16, 0.47, 1.61);
  transition: transform 0.25s 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.67, -0.16, 0.47, 1.61);
  transition: transform 0.25s 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.67, -0.16, 0.47, 1.61), -webkit-transform 0.25s 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.67, -0.16, 0.47, 1.61);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1) translateZ(0);
          transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1) translateZ(0);
}
.colorful-switch__on__inner:before, .colorful-switch__on__inner:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #ffffff;
}
.colorful-switch__on__inner:before {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 9px;
}
.colorful-switch__on__inner:after {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 9px;
  height: 100%;
}
.colorful-switch__off {
  position: absolute;
  left: 204px;
  top: 50%;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  margin-left: -32px;
  margin-top: -32px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.colorful-switch__checkbox:checked ~ .colorful-switch__label .colorful-switch__off {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-125px, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(-125px, 0, 0);
}
.colorful-switch__off:before, .colorful-switch__off:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s 0.25s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s 0.25s;
  transition: transform 0.25s 0.25s;
  transition: transform 0.25s 0.25s, -webkit-transform 0.25s 0.25s;
}
.colorful-switch__checkbox:checked ~ .colorful-switch__label .colorful-switch__off:before, .colorful-switch__checkbox:checked ~ .colorful-switch__label .colorful-switch__off:after {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
          transition-delay: 0s;
}
.colorful-switch__off:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scaleX(1) translateZ(0);
          transform: rotate(45deg) scaleX(1) translateZ(0);
}
.colorful-switch__checkbox:checked ~ .colorful-switch__label .colorful-switch__off:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scaleX(0) translateZ(0);
          transform: rotate(45deg) scaleX(0) translateZ(0);
}
.colorful-switch__off:after {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.67, -0.16, 0.47, 1.61);
          transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.67, -0.16, 0.47, 1.61);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) scaleX(1) translateZ(0);
          transform: rotate(-45deg) scaleX(1) translateZ(0);
}
.colorful-switch__checkbox:checked ~ .colorful-switch__label .colorful-switch__off:after {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
          transition-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) scaleX(0) translateZ(0);
          transform: rotate(-45deg) scaleX(0) translateZ(0);
}

</style>  
<body>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font size="200px">Room</font>
 
    
    
    <div class="colorful-switch" >
        <input type="checkbox" style=" position: relative;
    top: 20px;" class="colorful-switch__checkbox" id="cozinha"/>
          <label class="colorful-switch__label" for="cozinha">
            <span class="colorful-switch__bg" ></span>
            <span class="colorful-switch__dot" ></span>
            <span class="colorful-switch__on">
              <span class="colorful-switch__on__inner" ></span>
            </span>
            <span  class="colorful-switch__off"></span>
          </label>
        </div>  
    
         
         
    


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They stay on top of each other because the placement has been defined in the css.  You would need to either remove the:

```
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
```

from .colorful-switch and define the values elsewhere or have a different css class for each button.

This would be an example of having seperate css for each buttons position: https://jsfiddle.net/d6LaLgLk/

or: https://jsfiddle.net/d6LaLgLk/1/ which uses px instead of %

Comment: if you want to see: http://heitor.comxa.com/      (only click in 'entrar')